# Matrix problems, change of first row and column regardless of the shape of the matrix

Tags: python, arrays

I am currently trying to initialize an empty matrix, filled with `None`. Thereafter, I want to edit the first row and column. The problem is it won't work when the matrix isn't in square form.

The empty matrix is a function that fills it with `None`s.
I am then trying to fill first row and column with: `0`, `-2`, `-4`, `-6`, `-8`, ...

```
def empty_matrix(x,y):
    matrix = []
    for i in range(x):
        matrix.append([])
        for j in range(y):
            j = None
            matrix[i].append(j)
    return matrix

x = empty_matrix(3,6)
for i in range(len(x)):
    x[i][0] = i*-2
for j in range(len(x)):
    x[0][j] = j*-2
```

Comment: `for j in range(len(x[0])`. Also what is `empty_matrix`? A user-defined function?

Comment: The empty matrix is 3x6 matrix filled with 'None'

Comment: Saying it's a 3x6 matrix is not specific enough. Please be even more specific. Including the function is your question would be ideal.

Comment: i have added the function, i hope it will help.